# Remove grid, If grid element is empty?

Tags: html, css

I have grid setup for "Sidebar" and "Main Content" inside grid container. I want to remove "Sidebar" element if it's empty using css.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: 'sidebar main-content';
  min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  grid-area: main-content;
}

.grid-container > .sidebar:empty {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I can select "Sidebar" if it's empty. Can't select parent div.

Edit:

html:

```html
<div className='grid-container'>
  <div className='sidebar'>
    <Sidebar />
  </div>
  <div className='main-content'>
    <div>Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Eidt 2: This worked for me.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: 'sidebar main-content';
  min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  grid-area: main-content;
}

.sidebar:empty {
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: How does your HTML look like?

Comment: Anyway, you can get the answer in the duplicate or else you can try some custom JS to detect.